# server-start with dynamic server-name

Tags: server, emacs-daemon

I'm using `(server-start)` in my `init.el`, but I'd like to be able to launch multiple server instances, every time I launch emacs.

Today, `server-start` complains if the server is already launched.

It would be nice that if the server already exists, a new server name is automatically determined (like server2, server3), a new server instance launched, and the server name displayed in a message.

As I'm emacs lisp newbie, can someone please help scripting this in `init.el`?  How to determine if serverN is already launched? List `/tmp/emacs$UID`?

Comment: You could try use `server-start` from the command line: `emacs --eval '(progn (setq server-name "server2") (server-start))' file`

Answer (score 2):

> How to determine if serverN is already launched?

```
server-running-p is a compiled Lisp function in ‘server.el’.

(server-running-p &optional NAME)

Test whether server NAME is running.

Return values:
  nil              the server is definitely not running.
  t                the server seems to be running.
  something else   we cannot determine whether it’s running without using
                   commands which may have to wait for a long time.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the call `(server-start)` with following code in your `init.el`:

```
(require 'server)

(defun my--server-start ()
    (let ((server-num 0))
        (while (server-running-p (unless (eq server-num 0) (concat "server" (number-to-string server-num))))
            (setq server-num (+ server-num 1)))

        (unless (eq server-num 0)
            (setq server-name (concat "server" (number-to-string server-num))))
        (server-start)

        (setq frame-title-format server-name)))

(my--server-start)
```

Note: to connect to those servers, you have to use `emacsclient` like this:
`emacsclient -s server<SERVERNUMBER>`
Example: `emacsclient -s server2`